# Google sign in, how to correctly handle error case when user is required to sign in into the account again

Tags: android, google-signin

- I am working on the Google sign up implementation in my app. The sign up itself works correctly, but I am confused because I can't find a way to handle the next error.
- User saved Google account in his phone. This account appears in the Google account selection pop-up and can be used for sign up. The error will occurred if I change the Google account password and don't sign in again to my phone. Now when I try to use the Google account, I receive an error with the following status:

> googleSignInStatus=Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}

The screenshot of pop-up:[image: 1]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {    
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build()

mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build()

mGoogleApiClient?.registerConnectionFailedListener(this)
} //Code that is used to init sign in client

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        Timber.tag("TRY_TO_HANDLE").d(data.extras?.toString())
        Timber.tag("TRY_TO_HANDLE").d(result.status.toString())
        Timber.tag("TRY_TO_HANDLE").d(result.status.statusMessage)
}} //Code that handle result
  //googleSignInStatus=
       Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}
```

- I want to handle the error and show the Google sign in screen, so the user will sign into his account and will be able to use it in my app to sign up.
- I studied the official documentation but found nothing. I think that it is possible because some apps that support Google sign in work in this way (for example, AliExpress app).
- Can anyone explain to me how to implement it?

Comment: welcome to StackOverFlow

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the account and trying the signup again using.

```
mClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect()
```